# Win32 API support in WIndows 8.1 phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, wack

I heard that few of the Win32 APIs are not supported in Windows 8.1 phone. I have an c++ application which is using some Win32 APIs. How to check whether my application will work on Windows 8.1 phone?

Comment: Try to compile and run it on a Windows 8.1 phone?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list of supported Win32 functions on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). However, since it can be hard to match supported functions with your code, you might as well try to compile the code yourself and check the errors (if any).

It mostly depends on what you were doing with win32. The list of functions is quite limited IMHO.

Comment: I heard that there is a microsoft utility which will scan the code and tells you the supported and unsupported lines. do you know about that?

Comment: I am afraid not, I don't really use Win32 all that much these days.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to run the WACK (Windows Application Certification Kit).

1. Right-click project, choose **Store**, then **Create App Packages...**
2. Say "No" to upload packages, then click **Next**
3. Select ARM & x86 release builds, then click **Create**
4. Click **Launch WACK** on the next screen

You might have to download a WACK update before you can certify (it changes pretty regularly as new APIs are enabled).